# 'kubectl not found' while running through ssh-task bamboo

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, bamboo

I have created a job in bamboo and created a ssh-task to run on my server. My server has already installed kubectl and below command executed successfully there.

```
 echo `kubectl get namespace`
```

But while running command through job, its showing below error:

```
 bash: line 5: kubectl: command not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please be sure that kubectl binary is in PATH of the user context, that your job is running in.

Otherwise you should use absolute path of kubectl executable, e.g. /usr/bin/kubectl)

1. Indenity the location of kubectl executable: which kubectl
2. Move it from its current location to location included in PATH, e.g. "sudo mv ./kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl"

Comment: Thank you so much, kubectl was set at home in bin folder which is leading this issue.